# Alternative way to activate keyboard layout

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have three keyboard layouts: English, Russian and Greek.
I use first two very often, and the Greek is only needed when working on some statistical problems (from time to time).
My preferred way to switch layouts is Alt+Shift. But I always need to cycle through Greek layout even when I don't really need it.
Is there a way to switch between English and Russian with Alt+Shift, and to activate Greek with some other way?
I'm on Linux Mint 20 Ulyana MATE (which is similar to Ubuntu Focal).

Comment: Which desktop environment are you on?

Comment: Whats the OS???

Comment: Linux Mint is off topic at Ask Ubuntu. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation as you (often switching between 2 layouts and only rarely needing a third layout).

The way I did it is to have one script which is for switching between 2 frequent layouts:

```
currentLayout=$(setxkbmap -query | grep layout | awk '{print $2}')
if [ $currentLayout = "us" ]
then
    setxkbmap ru -option caps:escape && notify-send -t 1000 "RU"
else
    setxkbmap us -option caps:escape && notify-send -t 1000 "US"
fi
```

And have another script for the third layout:

```
setxkbmap gr -option caps:escape && notify-send -t 1000 "GR"
```

Then set two hotkeys for those two scripts. The way this works is if you're currently on Greek, activating the first script will switch to US (due to `else` statement) and then further activations of the first script toggles between US and RU.